# I get an error while trying to get the call history via API method in Voximplant

Tags: voximplant

I am trying to get the call history and sending custom data:

```
$recordingUrls = $voximplantHelper->getCallHistory($messageArr['customData']);,
```

and i get the following response:

```
{"result":[],"total_count":0,"count":0,"timezone":"Etc\/GMT","history_report_id":null,"error":null,"errors":null,"warnings":["Required 'from_date' parameter isn't set.","Required 'to_date' parameter isn't set."]}.
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the date range for your reports. You can read more in the documentation:
https://voximplant.com/docs/references/httpapi/history#getcallhistory